# Spark kafka streaming processing time increases exponentially

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, emr

I have a spark kafka streaming job. Below is the main job processing logic.

```
val processedStream = rawStream.transform(x => {
var offsetRanges = x.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges;
val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(x.sparkContext.getConf).getOrCreate();
val parsedRDD = x.map(cr => cr.value());

var df = spark.sqlContext.read.schema(KafkaRawEvent.getStructure()).json(parsedRDD);

// Explode Events array as individual Event
if (DFUtils.hasColumn(df, "events")) {
    // Rename the dow and hour
    if (DFUtils.hasColumn(df, "dow"))
        df = df.withColumnRenamed("dow", "hit-dow");
    if (DFUtils.hasColumn(df, "hour"))
        df = df.withColumnRenamed("hour", "hit-hour");

    df = df
        .withColumn("event", explode(col("events")))
        .drop("events");

    if (DFUtils.hasColumn(df, "event.key")) {
        df = df.select(
            "*", "event.key",
            "event.count", "event.hour",
            "event.dow", "event.sum",
            "event.timestamp",
            "event.segmentation");
    }

    if (DFUtils.hasColumn(df, "key")) {
        df = df.filter("key != '[CLY]_view'");
    }

    df = df.select("*", "segmentation.*")
        .drop("segmentation")
        .drop("event");

    if (DFUtils.hasColumn(df, "metrics")) {
        df = df.select("*", "metrics.*").drop("metrics");
    }

    df = df.withColumnRenamed("timestamp", "eventTimeString");
    df = df.withColumn("eventtimestamp", df("eventTimeString").cast(LongType).divide(1000).cast(TimestampType).cast(DateType))
        .withColumn("date", current_date());


    if (DFUtils.hasColumn(df, "restID")) {
        df = df.join(broadcast(restroCached), df.col("restID") === restro.col("main_r_id"), "left_outer");
    }

    val SAVE_PATH = Conf.getSavePath();

    //Write dataframe to file
    df.write.partitionBy("date").mode("append").parquet(SAVE_PATH);

    // filter out app launch events and group by adId and push to kafka
    val columbiaDf = df.filter(col("adId").isNotNull)
        .select(col("adId")).distinct().toDF("cui").toJSON;

    // push columbia df to kafka for further processing
    columbiaDf.foreachPartition(partitionOfRecords => {
        val factory = columbiaProducerPool.value;
        val producer = factory.getOrCreateProducer();
        partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => {
            producer.send(record);
        });
    });

    df.toJSON
        .foreachPartition(partitionOfRecords => {
            val factory = producerPool.value;
            val producer = factory.getOrCreateProducer();
            partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => {
                producer.send(record);
            });
        });
}
rawStream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges);
df.toJSON.rdd;
});

val windowOneHourEveryMinute = processedStream.window(Minutes(60), Seconds(60));

windowOneHourEveryMinute.foreachRDD(windowRDD => ({
val prefix = Conf.getAnalyticsPrefixesProperties().getProperty("view.all.last.3.hours");

val viewCount = spark.sqlContext.read.schema(ProcessedEvent.getStructure()).json(windowRDD)
    .filter("key == 'RestaurantView'")
    .groupBy("restID")
    .count()
    .rdd.map(r => (prefix + String.valueOf(r.get(0)), String.valueOf(r.get(1))));
spark.sparkContext.toRedisKV(viewCount, Conf.getRedisKeysTTL());
}));

streamingContext.start();
streamingContext.awaitTermination();
```

This job was running for almost a month without a single failure now today suddenly the processing time started increasing exponentially although there are no events being processed.

I am not able to figure out why it is happening. Below I am attaching screenshot of the application master.

[image: Batches]
[image: Batches]

Below is the graph for processing time

[image: Graph]

From the jobs tab in spark UI. Most of the time is spent on line `.rdd.map(r => (prefix + String.valueOf(r.get(0)), String.valueOf(r.get(1))));`

[image: Jobs]

Below is the DAG for the stage

[image: DAG]

This is just a small fraction of the DAG. The actual DAG is quite large but these same tasks are repeated upto total number of rdds in the window i.e, I am running a batch of 1 minute so a window of 30 minute is having 30 same repetitive tasks.

Is there any concrete reason why out of sudden the processing time started exponentially ?

Spark version: 2.2.0
Hadoop version: 2.7.3

NOTE: I am running this job on emr 5.8 cluster with 1 driver of 2.5G and 1 executor of 3.5GB.

Comment: @All Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: even I am also facing the same issue, please let me if you find any solutions.

Comment: Hi, Do you got any solution for this issue? if so please let me know.

Comment: @VenkadeshVenkat No I didn't get any solution for this. The spark community is not responsive. Do you also run your job on emr cluster.

Comment: @VenkadeshVenkat Can you post your code ? I want to have a look.

Comment: I solved my issue, in my code I have registertemptable , I am applying where condition on that table. After removing the filter I can able to solve the issue.

Comment: @VenkadeshVenkat Did you find out why this is the source of error ? I mean it's quite common to register temp table and apply filters on that.

Comment: still, now we did not find. We are on the way to find the root cause. Let you know if I found anything.

Comment: @VenkadeshVenkat Did you able to debug this ? I am facing this again.

Comment: Yes, I can able to solve. In my code, last-two-minute data I will register as temp table and I will query on that table using where condition. Because of this, my DAG and query execution increased. Please post your full code I will have a look.